# How to use react states in react context (Ionic react)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I try to understand how to use the context api in React.
Therefore, I would like to build an Ionic React app with three tabs. Let's say it's a counter app that displays the current value on each tab. Moreover, there should be an opportunity to click on an increase button on at least one tab.

Now my idea was to build the app like this:

**ContextProvider.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createContext } from "react";

export const Context = createContext();

type Props = {
 children?: React.ReactNode
};

const ContextProvider: React.FC <Props>= ({children}) => {
 const [value,setValue] = useState(0);
 return (
     <Context.Provider value={[value,setValue]}>
         {children}
     </Context.Provider>
 );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
[...]

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <ContextProvider>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/tab2">
            <Tab2 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/tab3">
            <Tab3 />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/tab1" />
          </Route>
        </IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={triangle} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 1</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={ellipse} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 2</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab3" href="/tab3">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={square} />
            <IonLabel>Tab 3</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
      </IonTabs>
    </IonReactRouter>
    </ContextProvider>
   
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

**Tab2.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import './Tab2.css';
import { Context } from '../components/ContextProvider';

const Tab2: React.FC = () => {
  const [value,setValue] = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Tab 2</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Tab 2</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
   
        <p>{value}</p>
        <button onClick={() => {setValue((prev:number) => prev+1)}}>Klick</button>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Tab2;
```

So my question is:
In the context provider, in the create Context method, I have to provide a default value. I was trying different things, but nothing worked. What do I have to provide there?
And a more general question: Is the general structure of the app correct (and useful)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what you did is correct, except the click event function on the button it was wrong. (<button onClick={() => {setValue((prev:number) => prev+1)}}>Klick)

it should be replaced by this:

```js
<button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>increase value</button>
```

**Here is my full solution:**

---

***ContextProvider.js***

```js
//imports
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const initialValue = 0;
const MyContext = createContext(initialValue);

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, MyContext };
```

***Page.js***

```js
//imports
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './provider';

export default function Home() {
  const { value, setValue } = useContext(MyContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>increase value</button>
      <h1>Value: {value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I use const initialValue = 0 and const MyContext = createContext(initialValue) I'm getting an error.
"TS246 Type 'number' is not an array type" as well as " TS2322: Type '(number | Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>)[]' is not assignable to type 'number'."

Comment: it's just a typescript error. I didn't provide typescript types on my solution.
you should specify the type of the context like this: 
const MyContext = createContext<Number>(initialValue)